# find the Laurent series of $\frac{3}{2+z-z^2}$ about the following domains

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to find the Laurent series of $\frac{3}{2+z-z^2}$ about the following domains:

(a) $B_1(0)$
(b) ann$(0;1,2)$
(c) ann$(0;2,\infty)$

so I have

(a) Note we can write
$$f(z)=\frac{3}{2+z-z^2}=\frac{3}{(1+z)(2-z)}=\frac{1}{1+z}+\frac{1}{2-z}.$$
Here, the first term has power series
$$\frac{1}{1+z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^n.$$
As for the later term, we write
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{2-z}&= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}})\\
    &=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^n}\\
    &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}.
\end{align*}
Therefore we have as the Laurent series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty ((-1)^n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})z^n$$
as desired. \ \
(b) On the annulus ann$(0;1,2)$ we have that
$$\vert \frac{z}{2} \vert <1, \vert \frac{1}{z} \vert <1.$$
Thus for $\frac{1}{1+z}$ we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{1+z}&=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}}\\
    &=\frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{z^n}\\
    &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\\
    &=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\end{align*}

is this correct for 1(a) and part of 1(b)?
And for $\frac{1}{2-z}$ we write the same thing basically but it has no singular parts? cause the $z$'s all have positive powers.

And I'm a bit stuck with the last one, I know $\infty>\vert z \vert >2$.

Comment: Note that $|2/z| < 1$ or $|z/2| > 1$.

Comment: is my series correct for the first part of b and part a? @Riemann

Comment: I think it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lvert z\rvert \gt2$:

$$\dfrac 1{1+z}=\dfrac 1z\cdot \dfrac 1{1-(-\frac 1z)}=\dfrac 1z\sum_{n\ge0} (-\frac 1z)^n$$, which is valid on $\lvert z\rvert \gt1$
and which is what you already did;
and

$$\dfrac 1{2-z}=-\dfrac 1z\cdot \dfrac1{1-\frac 2z}=-\dfrac 1z\cdot \sum_{n\ge0}(\dfrac 2z)^n$$.

Combining,  $$\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac {(-1)^n-2^n}{z^{n+1}}$$.